# IOS App First letter of the name lowercase

Tags: xcode

I need to change the name of an app in order to have its first letter set to lowercase, I tried by simply changing the name of the app but the package name changed automatically to something like: `myapp.temp_caseinsensitive_rename`

I then edited the package name in order to delete the `.temp_caseinsensitive_rename` part but now, even if the first letter of the app's name is lowercase when I install it it's still uppercase. Does anyone know what am I missing?
Do I need to keep the `.temp_caseinsensitive_rename` part?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the display name of your app in the target's info:

[image]

Comment: I've added the Bundle display name in my .plist file but still the app name starts with uppercase, damn why is it soo hard :(